# Streaming Cloudwatch Logs to Amazon ES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, elk

I'm using Fargate to deploy my application. To log the container logs, I'm using `awslogs` as the log-driver. Now I want to ship my logs to Amazon ES service. While going through the [docs](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/CWL_ES_Stream.md) for shipping, I encountered a note that mentions

```
Streaming large amounts of CloudWatch Logs data to other
destinations might result in high usage charges.
```

I want to understand what all will I be billed for while shipping the logs to ELK? How do they define `large amounts`?

Will I be billed for

a) Cloudwatch?

b) Log driver?

c) Lambda function? Does every log-line triggers a lambda function?

Lastly, is there still a possibility to lower the cost more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would look running fluent or fluentbit in another container along side your application https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/elasticsearch

You can send your logs direct to ES then without any cloudwatch costs.

**EDIT**

Here's the final solution, just in case someone is looking for a cheaper solution.

Run Fluentd/Fuentbit in another container alongside your application

Using the [Github Config](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/master/examples/fluent-bit/forward-to-aggregator/task-definition.json), I was able to forward the logs to ES with the below config.

```
{
    "family": "workflow",
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "log_router",
            "image": "docker.io/amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest",
            "essential": true,
            "firelensConfiguration": {
                "type": "fluentbit",
                "options":{
                   "enable-ecs-log-metadata":"true"
                }
            },
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "your_log_group",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "memoryReservation": 50
        },
        {
            "name": "ContainerName",
            "image": "YourImage",
            "cpu": 0,
            "memoryReservation": 128,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 5005,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "command": [
                "YOUR COMMAND"
            ],
            "environment": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
                "secretOptions": [],
                "options": {
                    "Name": "es",
                    "Host": "YOUR_ES_DOMAIN_URL",
                    "Port": "443",
                    "tls": "On",
                    "Index": "INDEX_NAME",
                    "Type": "TYPE"
                }
            },
            "resourceRequirements": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The `log_router` container collects the logs and ships it to ES. For more info, refer [Custom Log Routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_firelens.html)

Please note that the `log_router` container is required in the case of Fargate, but not with ECS.

**This is the cheapest solution I know which does not involves Cloudwatch, Lamdas, Kinesis.**

Comment: You mean using `awsfirelens` as the `logDriver`?

Comment: Ah, my bad fargate doesn't support fluentd log driver, ec2 ecs does.

Comment: Just looked at the docs and yes awsfirelens would work, doesn't look like they charge for it other than normal data transfer costs.

Comment: If you don't want to use firehose and can forward to another fluent container like this exampe https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/tree/master/examples/fluent-bit/forward-to-aggregator

Comment: I fail to understand what does `log_router` container do in https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/master/examples/fluent-bit/forward-to-aggregator/task-definition.json ? Have seen in almost all the examples. Any input on this?

Comment: Can't I just directly forward it to my `fluentd` fargate service? This additional container `log_router` would take up some space/memory in my instance.

Comment: I don't believe so, it uses a custom fluent bit build https://github.com/aws/aws-for-fluent-bit#plugins

Comment: Please allow me to edit your answer. Your answer was very close in helping me figure out the solution. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast Have you got the solution on this? Doing POC on the AWS elasticsearch for log management and need to know approx costing of log sreaming.

Comment: Hi can i use filebeat instead of fluent bit? @PrafulBagai

Answer (score 0):

Like every resource, AWS charges for use and for maintenance. therefore, the charges will be for the execution of the lambda function and Storing the data in CloudWatch. the reason they mentioned that: `Streaming large amounts of CloudWatch Logs data to other destinations might result in high usage charges.`  Is because it takes time for the lambda function to process the log and insert it into ES, When you try to stream a large number of logs the lambda function will be executed for a longer time.

- Lambda function? Does every log-line triggers a lambda function?

  Yes, when enabling the streaming from CloudWatch to ES every log inserted to CloudWatch triggers the lambda function.

Image from demonstration (see the trigger):

[image]

- Is there still a possibility to lower the cost more?

The only way to lower the cost (**when using this implementation**) is to write your own lambda function which will be triggered every X seconds\minutes and insert to log to ES.
As much as I can tell the cost gap will be Meaningless.

More information:

[Lambda code](https://github.com/AmitBaranes/Stream-to-ElasticSearch/blob/master/stream-to-elastic-lambda.js) .

[How this is working behind the scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58558891/9931092) .

Comment: How about using https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/master/examples/fluent-bit/forward-to-aggregator/task-definition.json ?? Wouldn't it be cheaper as compared to streaming data which involves cloudwatch, lambdas and kinesis? Your thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: I haven't tried this but sure if it's working the costs will be very very small. Can you share a little bit more about your architecture?

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please have a look. It does not involves Cloudwatch, Kinesis/Lambdas.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast Nice, at the time I faced this issue this was the only solution. thanks for sharing this with us.